# Error, opening json file

Tags: python, json

Some time ago, I wrote python dictionary in `json` file. Today, i appended some other information to that file like this:

```
with open('path.json', 'a') as fp:
    json.dump(DataDict, fp)
```

And tried to open it, using 2 methods:

```
with open('path.json', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
records = json.loads(content)
```

and

```
with open('path.json', 'r') as fp:
     File = json.load(fp)
```

But both ended up with error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-149-d027cfbf5e86> in <module>()
      3 with open('/home/vladislav/Документы/Diploma/data/News/ВТБ.json', 'r') as content_file:
      4     content = content_file.read()
----> 5 records = json.loads(content)

/home/vladislav/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    317             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    318             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 319         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    320     if cls is None:
    321         cls = JSONDecoder

/home/vladislav/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):
--> 342             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    343         return obj
    344 

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 462852 (char 462851)
```

How can i fix it? Internet seems to have no answer on the first sight.

Comment: There must be problem with your content, Can you paste it here ?

Comment: "*i appended some other information to that file like this ...*". You basically created a bitwise concatenation of two JSON files. And last time I checked, the bitwise concatenation of two JSON files is *never* valid JSON ...

Comment: @VidyaSagar I'm afraid, i cant. This is `json` - i cant view it.

Comment: You can view `json` in any text editor.

Comment: @dhke Bad news. Is there a way to retrive the appended part?

Comment: @Joseph Never succed in that. My laptop just fall in a deep lag, when i try to view it with `gedit`

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav Ah, so it is a very BIG `json` file...

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav Well, the first part should end at character `462850` or `462851`. Just copy the first `462851` bytes to a file and the remainder to a separate file. If that's insufficient, you'll have to bisect the actually error, but the split is around char `462850` or `462851`.

Comment: @Joseph is 462851 symbols considered big?

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav not especially, although some editors might choke on it. I'd expect SublimeText to handle it OK, although I have crashed it with big enough files. It might be worth your while to get this thing open in a text editor, because your problem might be fixed by changing `}{` to `,`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're corrupting the JSON by concatenating a new JSON object to it. Perhaps a better idea is to load the existing data, extend it, and re-save it:

```
import json

DataDict = ...

with open('path.json', 'rb') as fp:
    new_data = json.load(fp)
    new_data.update(DataDict)

with open('path.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(new_data, fp)
```

---

**Edit from comments:**

This is just an idea. If you have been concatenating JSON objects, and assuming that the top-level of the object is indeed an object (as in `{...}`) then perhaps this hack will work:

(Note: please save and back up this file before trying!)

```
import json

with open('path.json', 'rb') as fp:
    corrupted = fp.read()
    fixed_raw = b", ".join(corrupted.split(b"}{"))
    fixed = json.loads(str(fixed_raw, "UTF-8"))

with open('path-fixed.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(fixed, fp)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, I gained DataDict by a long-long web parsing procedure. That would be a big pain to re-start procedure. Is there a way to deal with corrupted `json`?

Comment: I had a `print` statement left in by accident while I was testing, if it's running very slow or if it crashes please see the updated code

Comment: line 5 produces:
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: I'am sorry, but that still ends with error;(
`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'`

Comment: Fixed, try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138431/discussion-between-ladenkov-vladislav-and-julien).